# Is there a way to save a game in progress?

Tags: game-engine

After being exported to a stand alone game, The player/s should be able to close the game and open it to the same place/setup/move at a later time. This is a longer game,and may not be finished in one sitting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own system. I tend to use json to encode data, but other people like pythons pickle module.

If you clarify your question, we can probably help more.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to write the data to be stored into bge.logic.globalDict (via Python).

The SaveActuator can write this dictionary to file and the LoadActuator can read it from file.

Be aware there is a limited set of data types that can be saved. For example you need to convert positions to list of floats and back.